# is not abstract and does not override abstract method & name clash

Tags: java

i get these two errors when i execute this code

> `error: SpringBeanFactoryPluginImpl is not abstract and does not override abstract method isTypeMatch(String,Class) in BeanFactory public class SpringBeanFactoryPluginImpl implements SpringBeanFactoryPlugin` 
>   `error: name clash: isTypeMatch(String,Class<?>) in SpringBeanFactoryPluginImpl and isTypeMatch(String,Class) in BeanFactory have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other   public boolean isTypeMatch(String s, Class<?> class1)`

---

```
public class SpringBeanFactoryPluginImpl implements SpringBeanFactoryPlugin,
    BeanFactory {

private static BeanFactory beanFactory = new XmlWebApplicationContext();

public boolean containsBean(String s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return beanFactory.containsBean(s);
}

public String[] getAliases(String s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return beanFactory.getAliases(s);
}

public Object getBean(String s) throws BeansException {

    return beanFactory.getBean(s);
}


private void checkBeanFactory(String string) throws FatalBeanException {

    try {
        Class clazz = Class.forName(string);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new FatalBeanException(string + " was not found.");
    }

}

public Object getBean(String s, Object[] aobj) throws BeansException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return beanFactory.getBean(s, aobj);
}

public Class getType(String s) throws NoSuchBeanDefinitionException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return beanFactory.getType(s);
}

public boolean isPrototype(String s) throws NoSuchBeanDefinitionException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return beanFactory.isPrototype(s);
}

public boolean isSingleton(String s) throws NoSuchBeanDefinitionException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return beanFactory.isSingleton(s);
}


public <T> T getBean(String s, Class<T> class1) throws BeansException {

    return beanFactory.getBean(s, class1);
}

public boolean isTypeMatch(String s, Class<?> class1)
        throws NoSuchBeanDefinitionException {

    return beanFactory.isTypeMatch(s, class1);
}

public <T> T getBean(Class<T> s) throws BeansException {
    return beanFactory.getBean(s);
}

}
```

Comment: Replace `isTypeMatch(String s, Class<?> class1)` by `isTypeMatch(String s, Class class1)`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `BeanFactory`'s `isTypeMatch` method's second argument has type `Class` (the raw type), rather than `Class<?>`, so you can't use `Class<?>` to implement it. You can fix it by changing this:

```
public boolean isTypeMatch(String s, Class<?> class1)
```

to this:

```
public boolean isTypeMatch(String s, Class class1)
```

This will give you a warning, which you can suppress by adding (depending on your compiler) either `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` or `@SuppressWarnings("raw")`.